# Проблема с пагинацией-

Tags: php

если в переменной `$page` значение `от 1 до 5` - нужно на выходе получить `1`

если в переменной `$page` значение `от 5 до 10` - нужно на выходе получить `2`

если в переменной `$page` значение `от 10 до 15` - нужно на выходе получить `3`

и так далее

как можно такое реализовать? в голову пока ничего не пришло =/. спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать округление вверх:

```
$size = 5;
foreach (range(1, 15) as $count) {
  $page = ceil($count / $size);
  $rest = ($count % $size) ?: $size;
  echo "Для \$count=$count, \$page=$page, \$rest=$rest\n";
}
```

Comment: спасибо. можете помочь ещё с этим вариантом https://note-pad.net/ru/read/c8a99ce711b5471fbe571904e9ce3aef ?

Comment: Добавил `$rest`

Comment: огромное спасибо!)